# Catel WPF Shutdown mode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I want to display second window using IUiVisualizaerService, and close\hide MainWindow. If i call CloseViewModelAsync on MainWindow, it will close entire application. Even if i specified Shutdown mode on App.xaml as OnLastWindowClose or OnExplicitShutdown. How can i override this behavior?

```
private async void OnOpenProjectExecute()
    {
        ProjectMainWindowViewModel viewModel = new ProjectMainWindowViewModel();
        this.uiVisualizerService.Show(viewModel);
        await this.CloseViewModelAsync(true);       
    }
```

**Edit**

I Changed my method to

```
 private Task OnOpenProjectExecute()
    {
        ProjectMainWindowViewModel viewModel = new ProjectMainWindowViewModel();
        this.uiVisualizerService.Show(viewModel);
        return this.CloseViewModelAsync(false);
    }
```

ExplicitShutdown working now, but newly created window still closing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to set the shutdown mode in app.xaml.cs
2. Tip: use TaskCommand instead if you need async commands

Comment: Thank you for tip. I also set ShutdownMode in App.xaml.cs in OnStartup method, but it doesn't help.
`this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;`

Comment: I Changed my method. ExplicitShutdown working now, but newly created window still closing. Any suggestions?